# Java Mouse Event Dispatch

Tags: java, events, awt, dispatch

Alright,

I have a JFrame which uses a classloader to load an Applet onto a JPanel, which is added to my JFrame.

The java Applet is a game in which I am trying to create a "bot" for.  I would like to be able to minimize my JFrame and allow the "bot" to continue to run.  This bot will only be clicking on x,y coordinates within the loaded Applet.

After doing research it seems I would want to fire Mouse events through the AWT event Dispatch onto my JFrame.  However this does not seem to work.

I think it is either the case that I am firing events to the wrong component, or am misunderstanding how dispatching mouseEvents actually work.

I am pretty stumped, and am hoping for any suggestions on what to do.

Thanks, -Tony

```
MouseEvent me = new MouseEvent(getContentPane(), // which
                                        MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, 
                                        System.currentTimeMillis(), 
                                        0, 
                                        50, 50, 
                                        1, 
                                        false); 
                                getContentPane().dispatchEvent(me);
```

UPDATE: My events are in fact getting dispatched, just not onto the applet that is loaded into the JFrame.  Why does the Applet not recognize the clicks? perhaps it is clicking behind the applet?

SOLVED: What I needed to do was fire a MOUSE_PRESSED and then MOUSE_RELEASED event.  Just firing MOUSE_CLICKED didn't actually do what I wanted.  I feel stupid that I spent so much time to figure that out.

Comment: Hello, please provide relevant code.

Comment: no idea ................

Comment: the comment is completely irrelevant to my problem lol.  just forgot to update the comment.

Comment: How did you add the mouse listener? It is working for me.

Comment: check my update @ BackSlash

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the java Robot class specifically, this:

```
Robot = new Robot();
```

then use the method mouseMove() e.g.

```
Robot.mouseMove(x,y);
```

then use the method mousePress/Release to simulate a click.

Comment: No the Robot class uses the system mouse, this is not what I want.  I need mouse events to be fired within the JFrame, while retaining complete control of the system mouse.

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to do was fire a MOUSE_PRESSED and then MOUSE_RELEASED event. Just firing MOUSE_CLICKED didn't actually do what I wanted. I feel stupid that I spent so much time to figure that out.